# Antiderivatives: Car Deceleration Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> A car braked with a constant deceleration of $40 \text{ ft}/\text{s}^2$, producing skid marks measuring $160 \text{ ft}$ before coming to a stop. How fast was the car travelling when the brakes were first applied?

I know I can solve this problem using kinematics equations from physics; using $v_f^2=v_i^2 + 2ad$ yields an initial velocity of $~113\text{ ft}/\text{s}$.  However, I am supposed to be using antiderivatives and not physics. So far, I figured that if $a(t)=-40$ then $v(t)=-40t+c_1$ and $d(t)=-20t^2+c_1x+c_2$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. I'm not quite sure what my next step should be... any suggestions? (Also, we haven't learnt integration yet, we're basically in the bridge stage between differentiation and integration.)

Comment: Hint: Writing $a$ to denote aceleration, $v$ to denote speed and $d$ to denote distance, we know that $v(t)=d'(t)$, $a(t)=v'(t)$ and therefore $a(t)=d''(t)$.

Comment: FYI, an $x$ somehow got into the equation for $d(t)$ in your question. I think you meant it to be a $t$.

Comment: Oops sorry, it should be a $t$! Thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equations are correct ( with a $t$ instead of $x$ in the second equation) and, if we measure the time and the space from the instant in which began the braking, in your  second equation we have $c_2=0$ ( the initial position is $d(0)=0$).  the other constant $c_1$ is the inital velocity $v(0)=c_1$ and at the instant $t_1$ in wich the car stops its motion we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
0=-40t_1+v(0)\\
160=-20t_1^2+v(0)t_1
\end{cases}
$$

solve this system and you find the duration of the braking $t_1$ and the inital velocity $v(0)$

Answer (score 0):

Now incorporate the known quantities.  If you measure $d(t)$ from the start, $d(0)=0$, which gives one constant.  If you let $t_0$ be the time at the end of the skid, you know $v(t_0)=0$.  Use the velocity equation to get $c_1$ in terms of $t_0$, then substitute$c_1$ into the $d$ equation.  You know $d(t_0)$ as well, which will give the other constant.  You are asked for $v(0)$